# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() python dbscan 3 dimensions point

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, ambiguous, dbscan

I want to do clustering using DBSCAN algorithm with a dataset that contains 3 points. This is the dataset :

```
1   5   7
12  8   9
2   4   10
6   3   21
11  13  0
6   3   21
11  13  0
3   7   1
1   9   2
1   5   7
```

I do clustering with this code :

```
from math import sqrt, pow

def __init__(eps=0.1, min_points=2):
    eps = 10
    min_points = 2
    visited = []
    noise = []
    clusters = []
    dp = []

def cluster(data_points):
    visited = []
    dp = data_points
    c = 0

    for point in data_points:
        if point not in visited:
            visited.append(point)
            print point
            neighbours = region_query(point)
            #print neighbours
            if len(neighbours) < min_points:
                noise.append(point)

            else:
                c += 1
                expand_cluster(c, neighbours)

#cluster(data_points)

def expand_cluster(cluster_number, p_neighbours):
    cluster = ("Cluster: %d" % cluster_number, [])
    clusters.append(cluster)
    new_points = p_neighbours
    while new_points:
        new_points = pool(cluster, new_points)


def region_query(p):
    result = []
    for d in dp:
        distance = (((d[0] - p[0])**2 + (d[1] - p[1])**2 + (d[2] - p[2])**2)**0.5)
        print distance
        if distance <= eps:
            result.append(d)
    return result

#p_neighbours = region_query(p=pcsv)

def pool(cluster, p_neighbours):
    new_neighbours = []
    for n in p_neighbours:
        if n not in visited:
            visited.append(n)
            n_neighbours = region_query(n)
            if len(n_neighbours) >= min_points:
                new_neighbours = unexplored(p_neighbours, n_neighbours)
        for c in clusters:
            if n not in c[1] and n not in cluster[1]:
                cluster[1].append(n)
    return new_neighbours

@staticmethod
def unexplored(x, y):
    z = []
    for p in y:
        if p not in x:
            z.append(p)
    return z
```

in this code there are `point` and `n` variables which are same with `data_points` that contains the dataset. If I read manual I guess this code can work actually, but when I run `cluster()` function there is an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-39-77eb6be20d82>", line 2, in <module>
    if n not in visited:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I don't know why this code still get that error, whereas I change `n` or `point` variable with index data. Do you have any idea what's wrong with this code ? how can I make it work?

thank you for your help..

Comment: You have serious problems with local and global variables in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `numpy`, you should use masks instead of lists:

```
def cluster(data_points, eps=0.1, min_points=3):
    cluster_numbers = numpy.zeros(len(data_points), dtype=int)
    c = 0
    for idx, point in enumerate(data_points):
        if cluster_numbers[idx] == 0:
            print point
            neighbours = region_query(data_points, point, eps)
            #print neighbours
            if sum(neighbours) < min_points:
                # noise
                cluster_numbers[idx] = -1
            else:
                c += 1
                expand_cluster(c, data_points, cluster_numbers, neighbours, eps)
    return cluster_numbers

def region_query(points, point, eps=0.1):
    distance = ((points-point)**2).sum(axis=1) ** 0.5
    return distance <= eps

def expand_cluster(cluster_number, points, cluster_numbers, new_points, eps=0.1):
    while True:
        indices = numpy.where(new_points & (cluster_numbers==0))[0]
        if not len(indices):
            break
        new_points = False
        for idx in indices:
            cluster_numbers[idx] = cluster_number
            new_points = new_points | region_query(points, points[idx], eps)
```

What you get is a array with integer numbers, one for each input point. Positions with -1 as value are noise points, 1 .. n are the different clusters.

So you can get the points for a cluster:

```
cluster_numbers = cluster(data_points)
noise_points = data_points[cluster_numbers == -1]
print "Total Clusters:", cluster_numbers.max()
for idx in range(1, cluster_numbers.max() + 1):
    cluster_points = data_points[cluster_numbers == idx]
    print "Cluster %d as %d points" % (idx, len(cluster_points))
```

Comment: thank you for the answers, sorry would you like to show how can I get the cluster and the number of cluster?

Answer (score 1):

The error emerges from these lines:

```
    if point not in visited:
        visited.append(point)
```

The `in` operator calls `list.__contains__`, which iterates over the items in the `visited` list to see if any of them are equal to `point`. However, equality tests between numpy arrays do not yield a single Boolean value, but rather an array of bools representing the element-wise comparisons of the items in the arrays. For instance, the result of `array([1, 2]) == array([1, 3])` is `array([True, False])`, not just `False`.

That's OK so far. Comparisons in Python are allowed to return whatever kind of object they want. However, when equality is being tested by `in`, it needs a Boolean result in the end, so `bool` is called on the result of the comparison. The exception you received comes from `bool(array([...]))`, which as the message says, is ambiguous. Should `bool(array([True, False]))` be `True` or `False`? The library refuses to guess for you.

Unfortunately, I don't think there is a really good way to work around this. Perhaps you could convert your points to tuples before saving them in `visited`? As a nice side effect, this would let you use a `set` rather than a list (since tuples are hashable).

Another issue you may have is that equality testing between floats is inherently prone to inaccuracy. Two numbers that *should* be equal, may not in fact be equal when compared using floats derived by different calculations. For instance, `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` is `False` because the rounding doesn't work out the same way on both sides of the equals sign. So, even if you have two points that *should* be equal, you may not be able to detect them in your data using only equality tests. You'd need to compute their difference and compare it to some small `espilon` value, estimating the maximum error that could have grown out of your computations.